# Converting a multi-dimensional php array into a JSON array of objects

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I need to create a multi-dimensional array in php and want to use it in a jQuery script as a JSON array of objects;

The required output in the jQuery script should look like this:

```
data = [
        { Month:'April', Comms:1000, Fees:200, Gains: 200},
        { Month:'May',   Comms:1200, Fees:300, Gains: 300}
        ]
```

Currently my php arrays are generated as follow:

```
    $data1[] = array(
        'Month' => 'April',
        'Comms' => 1000,
        'Fees'  => 200,
        'Gains' => 200      
    );      
    $data2[] = array(
        'Month' => 'May',
        'Comms' => 1200,
        'Fees'  => 300,
        'Gains' => 300      
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
```

My question is how to combine data1 and data2 into the data array in the json_encode php function which will produce the required jQuery JSON array of objects?

I do have the values of the different array fields and can create data1 and data2 in a different way, so the data is flexible and I can combine them in any other way which will produce the data array which will output them in the required JSON format.

Any help will be highly appreciated, I have seen question regarding this subject but none which address the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to merge both Arrays into a new Array of Arrays. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for more information.

```
$data = array_merge($data1, $data2);
echo json_encode($data)
```

or, more simply by using the `+` operator:

```
echo json_encode($data1 + $data2)
```

Comment: Thanks, as a matter of fact, I did tried $data1 + $data2 but I kept on getting only the first row. My situation is slightly more complicated than in my original question. I created these arrays in the model in a Joomla application, which return the combined array to the controller, where I use the json_encode. I tried to use the json_encode in the model and return that result to the controller but with the + operator only the first row was displayed but the array_merge did the trick.

Comment: Most likely a limitation of Joomla. I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
echo json_encode(array_merge($data1, $data2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
echo json_encode($data1 + $data2);
```

Note that you can also use `+` to merge arrays.

Comment: Thanks, this should work but for one reason or the other I could only get the first row. Could be because of the use on the model and controller in Joomla, but I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
echo json_encode($data1 + $data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

just user

```
echo json_encode($data1 + $data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make another array by extracting data from database by using groupBy months and store the data in other array.

```
$array = array();  
foreach ($data as $element) {
    $array[$element['month']][] = [ 'comms' => $element['comms'], 'fees' => $element['fees'], 'gains' => $element['gains']
}
```